# Getting the local 3D coordinates of object that was clicked on (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, 3d

I'm new to 3D programming, so bear with me.

I have a Path3D object, that is a triangle. I need the coordinates where it was clicked.

```
   MLength := Sqrt(9 - Sqr(1.5));

   P3D := TPath3D.Create(nil);
   P3D.SetSize(3, MLength, 0);
   P3D.Name := 'Front';
   P3D.OnMouseDown := Path3DMouseDown;
   P3D.OnMouseMove := Path3DMouseMove;
   P3D.OnMouseUp := Path3DMouseUp;
   P3D.MaterialBackSource := LightMaterialSource1;
   P3D.MaterialShaftSource := LightMaterialSource1;
   P3D.MaterialSource := LightMaterialSource1;
   P3D.Path.MoveTo(PointF(-1, 1));
   P3D.Path.LineTo(PointF(0, -1));
   P3D.Path.LineTo(PointF(1, 1));
   P3D.Path.LineTo(PointF(-1, 1));
   P3D.RotationAngle.X := -19.47;
   P3D.Position.Z := (-Sqrt(0.75) * 1.5) + (Sqrt(0.75) * 1.5) * 
                      Cos(DegToRad(70.53));
   P3D.Position.Y := 0;
   Dummy1.AddObject(P3D);
```

I've tried the following.

```
procedure TForm14.Path3DMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single; RayPos, RayDir: TVector3D);
begin

   TPath3D(Sender).RayCastIntersect(RayPos, RayDir, MoveBegin);
   MoveBegin := TPath3D(Sender).AbsoluteToLocal3D(MoveBegin);

end;
```

But i don't seem to get the result that i'm expecting. when clicking on top of the triangle i would expect something like (0, -1.299, 0), but thats not what i get. 
When reading the manual for the mousedown event it says:

"RayPos and RayDir specify the position and direction of the ray on which the mouse click was made"

I do not understand that. I understand ray casting from the camera, but the above, i do not understand.

Comment: When you click the mouse you actually cannot tell where it is clicked in the 3D space. It could be at any point in 3D space 'underneath' the mouse. The series of points that you could have clicked on is the ray, and the point is the point on that ray where the ray intersects the screen. At least, that is my understanding

Comment: BTW you don't test RayCastIntersect to see whether the ray does actually intersect the path. Therefore the MoveBegin value might not be valid.